# IntelliJ suggest underscore instead of camel case?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible in IntelliJ to change the suggestions of variable and object names to underscores instead of camel case?

For example when I'm typing out an object name IntelliJ suggests this: [image]

But I would like it to suggest: "task_manager"

Comment: `Java` stylistically should use camelCase instead of snake_case, just as a suggestion.

Comment: intellij knows best.

Comment: Please don't do that. Java isn't C, C++, or any other language where that would be customary. Stick to the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Is this _really_ necessary? As in, your boss says "use snake case for Java"? If it's an external requirement then alright, gotta get paid, but otherwise I'm with the previous commenters.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this because there wouldn't be much/any demand for such a feature given that it violates 'standard' java style.

Comment: I personally think that the comments are not very helpful. Since Intellij family also includes c-based IDEs (like CLion) its better to point out a possibility to that feature.